# Get id from <a> tag inside the same tag in html5

Tags: javascript, html

I want to get the id of an a tag inside the same a tag to then send it as an argument to javascript, if it's possible.
Something like this is what I've tried now:

```
var entity = document.createElement("a");
entity.setAttribute("id", name);
entity.setAttribute("href", "javascript:playAudio('"+path+"', this.id)");
```

I want it to be dynamic so that if the id changes the javascript call is done with the new id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using an `EventListener` is more appropriate in this case:

```
var entity = document.createElement("a");
entity.setAttribute("id", name);
entity.addEventListener("click", function(e){
    playAudio(path, this.id);
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be attaching an event handler instead of injecting JavaScript into the `href` attribute

```
entity.setAttribute('href', '#');
entity.addEventListener('click', function() {
    playAudio(path, this.id);
    return false;
}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Stick the javascript in the onclick. `this` in an href refers to **window** not the anchor.

```
var entity = document.createElement("a");
entity.setAttribute("id", name);
entity.setAttribute("onclick", "playAudio('"+path+"', this.id)");
```

Comment: Thank you, works great!
Happy to get nicer code too, I'm a bit curious though, why doesn't it work in the href?

Comment: @LukasKlingsbo - It's because `this` in `href` is referring to `window`.